# Selecting multiple columns from pandas DataFrame by labels and integers in single indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select columns 'd' and 'f', and the first two columns, whatever their name is, in that order, from my pandas DataFrame.

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 
   ...: 'c': [7, 8, 9], 'd': [10, 11, 12], 
   ...: 'e': [13, 14, 15], 'f': [16, 17, 18]})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [8]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[8]: 
   a  b  c   d   e   f
0  1  4  7  10  13  16
1  2  5  8  11  14  17
2  3  6  9  12  15  18

In [9]: df[['d', 'f'] + list(df.columns[:2])]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[9]: 
    d   f  a  b
0  10  16  1  4
1  11  17  2  5
2  12  18  3  6
```

Is there a better way? That is: more concise, elegant, or performant.

Comment: @sammywemmy. After df.columns = [1, 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], i.e. mixed types, my method still works. When doesn't it?

Comment: I'm guessing (I might be wrong), that Pandas knows how to handle mixed types for columns. So your method should always hold.

Comment: @sammywemmy, my comment was an answer to your first comment, which you seem to have removed. Apart from that, it's just an open question. I don't find it particularly ugly, but I'm learning and don't want to miss anything. In your removed comment, you seemed to favor `loc` instead of `[]`. For just columns and labels, `[]` should be better, right?

Comment: apologies. I deleted it because I realised it was essentially the same as yours, the only difference was the `loc`. selecting with just `[]` is for convenience.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No need to apologize, I will leave it as is then.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong w/your approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't say this is more elegant than what you're already doing, but here are some equally concise versions of your selection:

```
df[['d', 'f'] + [*df][:2]]  # python >= 3.5 only

    d   f  a  b
0  10  16  1  4
1  11  17  2  5
2  12  18  3  6
```

This uses label based slicing. the `[*df]` term unpacks `df`'s columns into a list, then uses that to slice according to the given range. If you have multiple independent ranges to slice, either save the output of `[*df]` in a variable for reuse, or see below.

Performance is also hard to pin down, since these are all operations on lists/headers (what we call DataFrame metadata) instead of the actual data. So if there are any performance bottlenecks in your code, it is not here.

---

You can convert your labels into int positional indexes and index using [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
l = df.columns.get_loc
df.iloc[:, np.r_[l('d'), l('f'), :2]]

    d   f  a  b
0  10  16  1  4
1  11  17  2  5
2  12  18  3  6
```

Comment: It took me a while to get my head around `*df`, but I get it now. A `DataFrame` can be interpreted as a `dict` of columns, whose keys are the column labels. So the unpacking it inside a list gives the list of column labels. Quite brilliant! Thanks also for teaching me `get_loc`, and `np.r_`. Even if they are overkill for my case, I will definitely try to remember them.